# Segmentation Fault when trying to lock a shared memory mutex

Tags: c, mutex, shared-memory

Segmentation fault on a shared memory mutex. I have a producer and a consumer processes respectively, the producer inits the shared memory, the shared memory mutex, and writes the data.

The consumer opens the shared memory, tries to lock and read the data.

Without the mutex, the consumer is able to read the data (the data will be inconsistent, but there are no seg faults)

There is a seg fault only when the consumer is trying to lock the mutex.

Changed the flags and the result is the same, checked the return values of the attr and mutex inits, which are all good.

I am a little lost, and I am quite new to working on shared memory.

Any flaws pointed out would be really helpful. Thanks!

Stack:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff79c0c8d in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff79c0c8d in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004008ec in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde18 "\210\341\377\377\377\177") at cons.c:41
(gdb) p cons_ptr
$1 = (test_str_t *) 0x7ffff7ff7000
(gdb) p cons_ptr->data[0] 
$2 = 873422052  
(gdb) p cons_ptr->magic 
$3 = 43981  
(gdb) p cons_ptr->shm_lock
$4 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 128, __spins = 0, __elision = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}, 
  __size = '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "\200", '\000' <repeats 22 times>, __align = 0}
(gdb) 


// Header:  

const char *pathname = "test_shm";

typedef struct test_str_{
    uint64_t            magic;
    int                 data[1024];
    pthread_mutex_t     shm_lock;
    uint64_t            magic2;
}test_str_t;

// Producer:  

#include "test_header.h"
#include <time.h>

test_str_t *ptr;

void init_mutex(pthread_mutex_t *mutex){
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd, i = 0, num_int = 1024, rc = 0;
    int size = num_int * sizeof(int);
    fd = shm_open(pathname, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("\n shm_open failed \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    rc = ftruncate(fd, sizeof(test_str_t));
    ptr = (test_str_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(test_str_t),
                    PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("\n mmap failed \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    rc = init_mutex(&(ptr->shm_lock));
    if(rc != 0) {
        printf("Mutex Init failed: rc:[%d]\n", rc);
        exit(0);
    }
    ptr->magic = 0xABCD;
    ptr->magic2 = 0xEF12;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(ptr->shm_lock));
        ptr->data[i] = i;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ptr->shm_lock));
    }
    return 0;
}

// Consumer:  

#include "test_header.h"
#include <time.h>

test_str_t *cons_ptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd, i = 0, num_int = 1024, rc = 0;
    int try_lock = 0;
    int size = num_int * sizeof(int);
    fd = shm_open(pathname, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("\n shm_open failed \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    cons_ptr = (test_str_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(test_str_t),
                    PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(cons_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("\n mmap failed \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(cons_ptr == NULL) {
        printf("\n NULL Ptr\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Magic: [0x%x] [0x%x]\n", cons_ptr->magic, cons_ptr->magic2);
    //int try_lock = pthread_mutex_lock(&(cons_ptr->shm_lock)); // SEG FAULT
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\nNumber:[%d]\n", cons_ptr->data[i]);
        sleep(1);
    }
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&(cons_ptr->shm_lock)); // SEG FAULT
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with checking the stack trace for segfault.

Comment: What do all the `pthread_*()` functions return?  You should begin by making sure those are working.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I did check the return values, they all return 0. They are good. The return value is 0, when I try to lock in the producer process.

Comment: @SergeyA - I have added the trace, it does look okay.

Comment: @Gerhardh - can you please tell me which missing information?

Comment: @senthamizcoder i replied to comment with logs or similar. I just wanted to ask you to add it to the question instead. Now that comment is gone.

Answer (score 4):

(1) one problem is here:
ptr->data = rand();
data is an int*, and you have replaced that pointer with a random address.  You do this in a couple of places and I'm not seeing **exactly** what is going on, but it's the most obvious mistake I see right now.

(2) The next thing I see is that in the consumer you open the file read only and map the memory as read only, but pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock would need to be able to modify the mutex, so that would probably cause some trouble.

Comment: thanks, I changed data[i] to point to point to the value of i itself, sadly I still get the same SEG fault. But the consumer is still able to retrieve the values of i as 0 through 4.

Comment: YES! That's the trick, setting it to write privileges on the consumer process made it work! Thanks! :)

Comment: It took me a second to notice it since I don't believe I have ever used that shared memory mechanism.  Surprising, since it looks to be extremely simple and useful...  If you are in good shape you should accept answer I think.  You are very welcome.